# How to find an index of a computable function?

Tags: computer-science, computability

> Is there an index $i$ such that $\phi_{p(i)}(0) = i + 2$, for a total computable function $p$?

I know about the s-m-n theorem and fixed point theorem, and how to apply them to some basic functions in order to show whether they are computable or not. But, I don't know, how can I find an index of a function as in the exercise above.

I mean, if I have a function like the one below

$$g(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1 & \mbox{if } x = y \\ \uparrow & \mbox{otherwise } \end{cases}$$

where $\uparrow$ means converges, then I can see that the function is computable. We let $t$ be its index, and by the s-m-n theorem we get $$g(x,y) \equiv \phi_{s_1^1(t,x)}(y)$$

$s_1^1(t,x)$ is a function only depending on the argument $x$ while $t$ is fixed, and hence it can be written as $f(x)$. By the fixed point theorem then $$\phi_{f(k)} \simeq \phi_k$$

But, as I said, I don't know how to approach this problem, I would like to see how people approach this kind of problems and solve them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Fix some $e$ such that $\varphi_e(0)=0$. Then what can you say about the (total computable) function $$p: i\mapsto e\quad ?$$

Comment: This seems pretty much like the fixed point theorem, $f(x) = x$.

Comment: @Yuko I do not understand your comment. The point of my hint is that there is **no** such $i$ for this $p$; think about it.

Comment: Okay, I was thinking about the fixed point theorem, but seems like it is not at all relevant here. So, what I see from there is this, in order to get $0$ as output, we need $i = -2$. And because we use the set $\mathcal{N}$ for the enumeration of functions, we cannot have a negative index?

Comment: @Yuko Yes. And actually the problem runs deeper than that. It's a good exercise to show that, for instance, there is a computable total $p$ such that for every $i$ we have $\varphi_{p(i)}(0)\not=7$. More generally, fix any total computable function $T$. Then there is some total computable $p$ such that for every $i$ we have $\varphi_{p(i)}(0)\not=T(i)$. (Why does this not contradict the fact that for every total $p$, there *is* some $i$ such that $\varphi_{p(i)}(0)=\varphi_i(0)$?)

Comment: @Yuko no, I can't really follow what you wrote. I mean exactly what I wrote in my comment above: if the condition has the form "$\varphi_{p(i)}(0)=T(i)$" for some total computable $i$, then it is *not* always satisfiable. However, this crucially relies on $T$ being *total*, so does not contradict the recursion theorem.